# Reverse Proxy For Rabbitmq?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rabbitmq

I have an Nginx Reverse Proxy for my HTTP services,

I Wonder is it a good idea to use the Nginx stream module to create Reverse

Proxy for my connections to my Rabbitmq?

What is the advantage of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same as most other reverse proxy set ups

- single point of TLS termination
- load balancing
- HA fail over
- only exposing the minimal ports required to the outside world